# Can we compile Azure IoT C SDK for ArmV4I platform?

Tags: c, windows, azure, windows-embedded-compact

I'm currently trying to compile the Azure IoT C SDK in ArmV4I. My system can't be modified or upgraded and the different solutions on internet to compile only Arm (ArmV7) doesn't match with my machine.

Machine specs :

CPU : i.MX6 solo (ArmV4I)

OS : Windows CE 7.00 build 2882

I'll try to respond as fast i can, thanks for all the users that will try to help me.

I've already tried to compile the Az IoT SDK on CMAKE with the Windows mobile 5 SDK coupled with VS 2008 but it doens't run.

I also tried to build and execute an ARM project on recent Visual Studio with the right SDK but i noticed that was built in ArmV7, which doesn't work on my device.

I've tried many solutions that we can find on this platform and others to solve my problem but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

`Azure IoT C SDK` supports ARM platforms starting from ARMv7-A architecture and above.

And it does not officially support the `ARMv4I architecture`, which is the architecture of your `i.MX6 Solo processor`.

If your system cannot be upgraded, it may not be possible to compile and run the Azure IoT C SDK directly on your device. The SDK has dependencies on newer features and instructions provided by the ARMv7-A `architecture and are not available in ARMv4I`.

> As you mentioned trying to compile with different SDKs and tools, but none of them worked.

if it's possible to upgrade your hardware: If you have control over the hardware, you could consider upgrading to a device that supports at least the ARMv7-A architecture. This would enable you to use the Azure IoT C SDK without any major compatibility issues.

Need to find alternative IoT frameworks or libraries that provide support for the ARMv4I architecture. And it's important to note that compatibility and feature availability may be limited compared to the widely-used Azure IoT C SDK.

To connect [IoT Central Azure SDK C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139262/how-to-generate-command-output-in-iot-central-azure-sdk-c)

For more information, please refer to the [MSDoc1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-develop/concepts-using-c-sdk-and-embedded-c-sdk.md) and [MSDoc2.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-develop/about-iot-develop.md)